Error al importar Payutogui
Tras hacer una ejecucion para un codigo de captura, me muestra el siguiente error, ya intente instalar y desinstalar la libreria pero de cualquier forma sigue ocurriendo.
ImportError: cannot import name 'pyautogui_win' from partially initialized module 'pyautogui' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\usuariox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_init.py)

Hay un error con tus importaciones, al parecer hay un choque como se menciona ahí. Edita la publicación y muestra como has hecho las importaciones. No tienes redundancia de nombres cierto? Si recuerdas como lo instalaste, igual deja el orden de lo que hiciste.

Estos errores con paquetes de terceros típicamente son causados por nombrar un módulo propio con nombres que entren en conflicto con el paquete, como  nombrar tu script "pyautogui.py", conflicto con otros paquetes instalados (raro con paquetes "populares", pero puede pasar), etc. No obstante, aunque no pones la traza completa de la excepción, posiblemente el error en tu caso esté relacionado con https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/525. ¿Qué versión de PyAutoGUI tienes instalada (lo puedes ver por ejemplo con pip freeze)?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
